# How do I append two Streams in Java 8?

Tags: append, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have two streams of the same type. Is it possible to append one stream to the other without converting them to lists beforehand?

Example:

```
Stream<MyClass> ms = ...;
Stream<MyClass> ns = ...;
return ms.append(ns);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

Use `Stream.concat(stream1, stream2)`, this will create a stream consisting of first the elements of `stream1` and then the elements of `stream2`, *if* you want to maintain ordering. Also note that all applied predicates, etc. still work on a per-stream basis, they do not automagically hold for the concatenation of the two streams.

Comment: Ahh, silly me. Next time I will certainly use an thesaurus to cover all possible alternative terms of what I am looking for in the documentation :-)...